# Request to unblock port 25 on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I'm trying to request to unblock port 25 on my ec2 instance. I know very well that whatever they put as (optional) is 100% not optional. I've been asked over and over again to repeat these steps.

```
(Optional) Provide the AWS-owned Elastic IP addresses that you use to send outbound emails as well as any
reverse DNS records that AWS needs to associate with the Elastic IP addresses. With this information, AWS 
can reduce the occurrences of emails sent from the Elastic IP addresses being marked as spam.
```

How do I complete these below actions?

- What is the elastic ip address that I used to send outbound emails and how do I get it?
- What is the reverse dns record for that elastic ip address and how do I get it?

The request also asks me to do this:

```
If you're using Amazon Route 53 as your DNS service, either create a new resource record set that 
includes an A record, or update your existing resource record set to include a new A record.
```

It doesn't specify what the A record value should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to provide:

**What is the elastic ip address that I used to send outbound emails and how do I get it?**

This is the public IP address of your instance(s) that will be sending the emails on port 25. Make sure you have allocated an elastic IP address to the server(s).

**What is the reverse dns record for that elastic ip address and how do I get it?**

Traditionally this is where someone might create a PTR record containing the EIP and port number (25) and map this to a domain (e.g. smtp.example.com). You will need to provide AWS with the domain name that emails will send from so if you were sending from `hello@example.com` they would whitelist `example.com`.

**Adding A Record**

And for the extra of set an A record they are asking you to bind your domain e.g. `example.com` to the elastic IP address of the server in your DNS configuration. This is to prove you control the domain that you're wanting to send emails from.

Comment: Thanks for answering the two first questions of mine, I'll take a look further into them. Is adding the elastic ip adress of the server to the dns configuration mandatory? I have it so that `(www).example.com` points to/binded to a cloudfront distribution.

Comment: I believe the domain requirement is Amazon validating that because you want to send email from `example.com` that you have control (same as when a CA attempts to generate your SSL). You could set your emails to come from a subdomain such as `mail.example.com` to split your resolution between frontend application and mail service.

Comment: So add an A record like so: name: (mail.mydomain.com) - value: (EIP)? And for the second question, would I have to create a new hosted zone, or simply add a PTR record to my current one for my domain and have the name be (smtp.mydomain.com)? And would the value be EIP.25? Apologies if I sound really stupid.

Comment: So add an A record to a domain you would send email from (i.e. the from address of your emails) the suggestion is use a subdomain of your choice. Regarding the second question I believe they're just asking for the domain (same one as A record) to whitelist but traditionally this is where an engineer created the PTR record. And if you do need to create it then it would be in your existing hosted zone. :)

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll accept this. But one more thing again, will the value for the PTR record just be `EIP.25` or just the EIP alone.

Comment: It will map just the EIP to the domain, however you should not need to do this part. It will be done on Amazons end :)